# Measuring electricity usage with TECKIN smart plug

Tags: smart-plugs

I bought a smart plug, which doesn't seem to support measuring electricity usage with its native app.

I am wondering what the chance is, that this is a pure software feature and if I would be able to measure electricity usage by simply using a different app?

If yes, what app could I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Measuring power usage requires dedicated hardware. If the manufactures app doesn't support that feature it is very unlikely the required hardware is present in the device.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079Q5W22B), the Teckin SP20 supports it.

Also according to that Amazon page, the item does not have a UL listing.  They claim to be *applying* for an ETL listing, which would be equivalent.  In the meantime

> It is total safe,you do not have to worry at all.